# Sharepoint 2013 REST API issue when using author and lookup field together

Tags: sharepoint-addin, angularjs

My REST URL
The problem is that when i use author and employee location togther rest url is not formed.

**REST URL**

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Ventile')/items$select=Name,LastDatePUCDone,IsTerminated,Author/Title&$expand=Author/ID,EmployeeLocation/Title&$expand=EmployeeLocation
```

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script><script>
var spApp=angular.module('spApp',[]);
spApp.controller('spListCtrl',function($scope,$http){
$http(
{
    method: "GET",
    url:"/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Ventile')/items?$select=Name,LastDatePUCDone,IsTerminated,Author/Title&$expand=Author/ID",
    headers:{"Accept":"application/json;odata=verbose"}
}
).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
    $scope.xData=data.d.results;
    console.log(data.d.results);
}).error(function(data,status,headers,config){

});
});
</script>
<div ng-app="spApp">
<div ng-controller="spListCtrl">
<p><input type="text" ng-model="search"></p>
<table witdh="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>PUC Date</th>
<th>Is Terminated</th>
<th>Author</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="x in xData | filter : search">
<td>{{x.Name}}</td>
<td>{{x.LastDatePUCDone}}</td>
<td>{{x.IsTerminated}}</td>
<td>{{x.Author.Title}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `EmployeeLocation`, you must have it in your `$select` list, also, you can't have `$expand` in there twice.

Right:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Ventile')/items$select=Name,LastDatePUCDone,IsTerminated,Author/Title,EmployeeLocation/Title&$expand=Author/Title,EmployeeLocation/Title
```